# What is the chance of a Sacrifice Room to appear on a floor?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I'd like to know the probabability of a *Sacrifice Room* to appear on a floor. For me it feels like 33% or 50%. Does someone have more reliable data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I've found, there is no set *chance* to find a sacrifice room on any given floor, however, according to the wikia:

> Sacrifice rooms are more likely to be spawned if the player has full HP (Soul hearts will add up as well).

Source: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Sacrifice_Room